# Using unprocessedItems() to mock response of batchWrite

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a function to process 25 delete requests at a time and it uses batchWrite from DynamoDb.
My function checks if there are any unprocessedDeleteItems (as batchwrite can fail) and retriggers the batchWrite operation.

Using software.amazon.awssdk.dynamodb-enhanced:2.20.79

However, I am not able to mock this behavior in a Mockito unit test case.

```
Map<String, List<WriteRequest>> unprocessedRequests = new HashMap<>();

List<WriteRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();

items.forEach(item -> {
  Map<String, AttributeValue> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
  valueMap.put("Id", AttributeValue.fromS(item.id()));
  DeleteRequest request = DeleteRequest.builder().key(valueMap).build();
  requests.add(WriteRequest.builder().deleteRequest(request).build());
});

unprocessedRequests.put(tableName, requests);

BatchWriteResult val = BatchWriteResult.builder().unprocessedRequests(Collections.unmodifiableMap(unprocessedRequests)).build();
var builder = WriteBatch.builder(Test.class).mappedTableResource(mockAsyncTable);
when(mockDbClient.batchWriteItem(BatchWriteEnhancedRequest.builder().writeBatches(builder.build).build()).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(val));

System.out.println("expect nonempty: " + val.unprocessedDeleteItemsForTable(mockAsyncTable));
```

The print statement shows the value is empty, and not reflecting what I set with unprocessedRequests method call.
Can anyone help me here? I am not sure why this is not working as expected.
thanks.